# cats.ReaderT[F,A,B] from dependency A in for-comprehension

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, monad-transformers, scala-cats, for-comprehension

Here is a usecase:

```
import cats.data.ReaderT
trait Service{
  type OptionFromMap[A] = ReaderT[Option, Map[String, String], A]
  def f1(nameKey:String): OptionFromMap[String] = ReaderT(_.get(nameKey))
  def f2(addressKey:String, name:String): OptionFromMap[String] =
    ReaderT(map => Option(s"name: $name, address: ${map(addressKey)}"))
}
trait Service2 {
  type Env = (Service, Map[String,String])
  type OptionFromEnv[A] = ReaderT[Option, Env, A]
  import cats.syntax.applicative._
  import cats.instances.option._
  def f(nameKey:String, addressKey:String): OptionFromEnv[String] =
    for {
      //wrong try:
      s1 <- ReaderT((_:Env) => Option((_:Env)._1))
      //wrong try:
      s2 <- (_:Env).pure[OptionFromEnv]
      name <- s1.f1(nameKey).local((_: Env)._2)
      r <- s1.f2(addressKey, name).local((_: Env)._2)
    } yield r
}
```

So I want to be able to invoke `f1` and `f2` methods of `Service`.

The question is how to do it inside for-comprehension. Via `ReaderT.apply`, I can get it done via:

```
  def c(nameKey:String, addressKey:String): OptionFromEnv[String] =
    ReaderT(env =>
      (for {
        name <- env._1.f1(nameKey).local((_: Env)._2)
        r <- env._1.f2(addressKey, name).local((_: Env)._2)
      } yield r)
      .run(env)
    )
```

But I try to achieve something, that looks like:

```
import cats.data.Reader
trait Service{
  def f1: Reader[Map[String, Int], Int] = Reader(_("name"))
  def f2: Reader[Map[String, Int], Int] = Reader(_("age"))
}
trait Service2 {
  type Env = (Service, Map[String,Int])
  def f(i: Int): Reader[Env, Int] =
    for {
      s <- Reader((_: Env)._1)          //extract input type Service 
      r1 <- s.f1.local((_: Env)._2)
      r2 <- s.f2.local((_: Env)._2)
    } yield r1 + r2 + i
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace

```
//wrong try:
s1 <- ReaderT((_:Env) => Option((_:Env)._1))
```

with

```
s1 <- ReaderT((env: Env) => Option(env._1))
```

Comment: can you please explain, why in example with Reader, _ works, but with ReaderT does not?

Comment: @Alexandr Look at types. `s1 <- ReaderT(???)` expects `A => F[B]` i.e. `Env => Option[Service]` and `(_:Env) => Option((_:Env)._1)` has type `Env => Option[Env => Service]`.

Answer (score 0):

Found additional way to solve it via `Kleisli.ask`. Cannot say which option is better. Just as an alternative:

```
trait Service2 {

  def f(nameKey:String, addressKey:String): OptionFromEnv[String] =
    for {
      env <- Kleisli.ask[Option, Env]
      s <- Kleisli.pure(env._1)
      name <- env._1.f1(nameKey).local((_: Env)._2)
      r <- s.f2(addressKey, name).local((_: Env)._2)
    } yield r
}
```

In general, we have a way to get access to `env`, inside of the for-comprehension. For sure it is not necessary to get also `s` from `env`.